# Maven BuildNumber Plugin Git SSH

Tags: git, maven

I have a maven project that uses the `buildnumber-maven-plugin` and I have changed my git remote as I moved the project from GitLab to GitHub, but now when I try to run `mvn clean install` I get the error

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname github.com:lukebrewerton: Name or service not known
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

But I can clone the GH repo using my command line and push/pull etc, it just seems to be the maven command that doesn't work.

My pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>net.socialgamer</groupId>
  <artifactId>pyx</artifactId>
  <version>0.7.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>pyx</name>

  <scm>
    <url>https://github.com/lukebrewerton/cahds</url>
    <connection>scm:git:ssh://git@github.com:lukebrewerton/cahds.git</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:ssh://git@github.com:lukebrewerton/cahds.git</developerConnection>
  </scm>

....
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>create</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <doCheck>true</doCheck>
          <doUpdate>true</doUpdate>
          <revisionOnScmFailure>0</revisionOnScmFailure>
          <shortRevisionLength>7</shortRevisionLength>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

Comment: Maven committer here: Run in debug mode (-X) and we'll see the cause.

Comment: I have created a pastebin of the debug output here:- https://pastebin.com/TBu4vJuZ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have two issues here:

- The format in the POM does not correspond to the one required: `scm:git:ssh://server_name[:port]/path_to_repository` (https://maven.apache.org/scm/git.html).
- The URL passed to Git does not correspond to the formats Git supports: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull#URLS

As far as I can see, the clone button in GitHub provides an invalid URL for both Maven and Git itself. Otherwise you should file this with SCM and I will take a look at it.

Comment: I have raised this with GitHub support to revise the button text to avoid such problems in the future.